# Как по нажатию элемента recycler view открыть fragment?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

У меня в activity есть фрагмент с recycler view (вертикальный список). Как сделать так, чтобы по нажатию любого элемента в этом списке открывался другой фрагмент?
Вот код адаптера recycler view.

```
public class MessagesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessagesAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private MessagesFragment mContext;
private ArrayList<MessagesObject> MessagesArrayList;

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView name, description, timestamp, count;
    public ImageView avator;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        avator = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_chat_avatar);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_title);
        description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_message);
        timestamp = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_chat_date);
        count = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_chat_unread_count);
    }
}


public MessagesAdapter(MessagesFragment mContext, ArrayList<MessagesObject> MessagesArrayList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.MessagesArrayList = MessagesArrayList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_messege, parent, false);

    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    MessagesObject songs = MessagesArrayList.get(position);
    Glide.with(mContext).load(R.drawable.a_avator).into(holder.avator);
    holder.name.setText(songs.getMessagesName());
    holder.description.setText(songs.getMessagesDescription());
    holder.timestamp.setText(songs.getMessagesTime());
    holder.count.setText(songs.getMessagesUnread());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return MessagesArrayList.size();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Делаешь интерфейс который будет ловить клик на итем в твоем списке и передавать в активити и уже в активити взависимости какой итем выбрал через swich запускаешь нужный фрагмент

Comment: открываться должен один и тот же фрагмент, просто данные будут разные

Comment: реализации это не меняет.

Comment: Это должен быть принятый ответ (только кода бы сюда)

Answer (score 0):

Требуется добавить `OnClickListener` для `ViewHolder`, который будет делать что-то в таком плане:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view){
     AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();
     Fragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
     activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

Comment: это надо в адаптере писать? Если да, то начинает красным подсвечиваться view.getContext();

Comment: Добавьте для ViewHolder интерфейс OnClickListener, и переопредилите его как описано в ответе. И в конструкторе ViewHolder добавьте этот слушатель на view. Так же можно добавить этот код и в слушателя onCreateViewHolder, как сделано у вас сейчас. И что конкретно говорится в ошибке (которая подчерктивается красным).

Comment: Адаптер... Пробивается в активити, ломится к фрагмент менеджеру и меняет его?... Мне кажется лучше интерфейс создать... Пусть адаптер уведомляет активити, а она УЖЕ САМА СЕБЯ поменяет

Comment: К тому же может быть там простая `Activity`. Безопаснее всего вернуть данные в активити, чем кастить контексты к активностям. Господи

Comment: Можно создать и интерфейс, и да, это более правильный подход.
Но выбрал этот пример, потому что: вариант с интерфейсом упомянут выше, этот вариант более прост для понимания, быстрее и проще привести пример кода.
P.S. В английской ветке этот пример тоже регулярно используется, при том явно не последними людьми в Андроид разработке. Не нужно так резко реагировать на все, что вам не нравится.

Comment: Тем более, StackOverflow всегда в своих рекомендациях делает акцент именно на примере кода, который будет понятен для спрашивающего. Даже самый лучший ответ, который будет сохранять все принципы Clean Architecture, но при этом не будет приводить пример реализации, или же он будет чрезмерно объемным - может не принести человеку никакой пользы для решения его проблем.